# Unicode Character Outside of Quote Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, utf

Im using python3, and i'm trying to print a unicode character called hangul filler, when i assign just that character to a variable, and I check the variable, or print it with something else, it pushes the character to outside of the string, example below

```
#lets say the letter A is the broken character
s = a
s
''a
print(a + 'sss|')
sss|a
```

This doesn't happen with other UTF-8 characters, im not sure what to do

Comment: Change terminal/console. To me it seems a bug with such special characters on some terminals. Hangul has also a special handling in Unicode (but also in sharper library), so I'm not surprised if just your terminal do not support such "special case". Try to save it into a file, to be sure it is terminal and not your particular python version which has problems

Comment: Are you referring to U+3164 HANGUL FILLER?  Provide the actually string that produces your problem instead of a hypothetical example and describe your terminal environment.